# Vertical Align a Paragraph With Only HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to create a HTML code for a mail signature.

[image]

```
<p>
<a style="color: #191919; font-family: Open Sans; line-height:3" href="mailto: example@gmail.com" <img src="img.png"/></a> 
<a style="color: #191919; font-family: Open Sans;" href="mailto: =example@gmail.com">example@gmail.com</a> </p>
```

I want the text to be vertically aligned to the middle of the line.
Is there any way to achieve it without using CSS? (The email interface doesn't support CSS).
It's supposed to eventually look like that:

[image]

Line-height didn't work for me. Does anyone have any suggestion how to achieve it without CSS?

Comment: did you tried ` text-align: center`?

Comment: You are using CSS in the code sample you used in the style attribute. Also, do you mean horizontally aligned?

Comment: You can achieve this with tables and the v-align attribute of a <TD>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `vertical-align: text-top;`

Here is an article on the vertical_align property if you have any more questions:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

This may seem counter-intuitive (it does to me), but, in situations like this, you *always* need to apply the CSS style:

```
vertical-align: middle
```

to the **image**, rather than to the text.

Like this:

```
a img {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
a {
 color: #191919;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

a img {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
<a href="mailto: example@gmail.com">
<img src="img.png" />
example@gmail.com
</a>
</p>
```